# UWSGI Error with Nginx/Django deployment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web'

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

I have been trying to solve this for 3 days now.

I can not get uwsgi to load my app correctly.  I have tried using virtual environments, rebuilding a new EC2 Ubuntu instance, config changes, different versions of uwsgi, but nothing works.

I have another working setup that is the exact same, sans versions, EC2, uwsgi, nginx, django.

UWSGI should start with my wsgi.py file, but for some reason it seems like it is looking for a python module named "web" which is the name of my django project.  Here are the uwsgi logs:

```
Thu Nov  9 14:11:33 2023 - spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 24452, cores: 1)
Thu Nov  9 14:17:33 2023 - SIGINT/SIGTERM received...killing workers...
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - worker 1 buried after 1 seconds
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - goodbye to uWSGI.
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.20-debian (64bit) on [Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023] ***
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - compiled with version: 11.2.0 on 21 March 2022 11:00:44
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - os: Linux-6.2.0-1015-aws #15~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct  6 21:37:24 UTC 2023
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - nodename: ip-172-31-30-103
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - machine: x86_64
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - clock source: unix
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - pcre jit disabled
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - detected number of CPU cores: 1
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - current working directory: /
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - writing pidfile to /run/uwsgi/app/django/pid
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - chdir() to /home/ubuntu/websites/web
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - your processes number limit is 3738
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - your memory page size is 4096 bytes
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - detected max file descriptor number: 1024
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /run/uwsgi/app/django/socket fd 3
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - setgid() to 33
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - setuid() to 33
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - Python version: 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0]
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - *** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - Python main interpreter initialized at 0x5645069cac10
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - mapped 145840 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
Thu Nov  9 14:17:34 2023 - *** Operational MODE: single process ***
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wsgi'
Thu Nov  9 14:17:35 2023 - unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web/wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 217, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web'
Thu Nov  9 14:17:35 2023 - unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
Thu Nov  9 14:17:35 2023 - *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
Thu Nov  9 14:17:35 2023 - *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
Thu Nov  9 14:17:35 2023 - spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 24914)
Thu Nov  9 14:17:35 2023 - spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 24919, cores: 1)
```

This is my "/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/django.ini" file:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /home/ubuntu/websites/web
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=web.settings
wsgi-file = web/wsgi.py
processes = 1
module = wsgi:application
plugins = python3
master=True
```

Here is my "/home/ubuntu/websites/web/web/wsgi.py" file:

```
"""
WSGI config for web project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

#os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'web.settings'
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'web.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This is my project directory:

```
/home/ubuntu/websites/web/
    db.sglite3
    manage.py
    web.sock
    gg/
       (gg django app)
    web/
        settings.py
        asgi.py
        wsgi.py
```

My settings.py has my allowed host and the WSGI_APPLICATION = 'web.wsgi.application'

I am running uwsgi 2.0.20-debian and Python 3.10.12.  I am not currently using a virtualenv, I wanted to use one early on, but in my troubleshooting I wanted to eliminate that being an issue so I got rid of it. I also am running uwsgi that I installed with apt.  I have tried installing with pip, but it also does not work.